# Total probability question.

Tags: probability

Tennis player at Monday had $4$ used and $5$ unused tennis balls. Then, on Tuesday, he randomly picked and used three of them. On Wednesday, he picked one used and one unused ball. What is the probability that he picked two used balls on Thursday?

Here are all of the events:

$B$ player picked two used balls on Thursday

$H_1$ player picked three used balls on Monday

$H_2$ player picked three unused balls on Monday

$H_3$ player picked two used balls and one unused on Monday

$H_4$ player picked two unused balls and one used on Monday

This alone would require total probability formula:

$$P(B)=P(H_1)P(B|H_1)+P(H_2)P(B|H_2)+P(H_3)P(B|H_3)$$

However, that Wednesday makes a mess here so obviously, I cannot use this formula at least not this way. Any suggestion appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T$ denotes the number of unused balls used on Tuesday.

$$P(T=0)=\frac{4}{9}\cdot\frac{3}{8}\cdot\frac{2}{7}=\frac{24}{504}\\
P(T=1)=\binom31\cdot\frac{4}{9}\cdot\frac{3}{8}\cdot\frac{5}{7}=\frac{180}{504}\\
P(T=2)=\binom32\cdot\frac{4}{9}\cdot\frac{5}{8}\cdot\frac{4}{7}=\frac{240}{504}\\
P(T=3)=\frac{5}{9}\cdot\frac{4}{8}\cdot\frac{3}{7}=\frac{60}{504}\\$$

The number of used balls by Tuesday is $4+T$.

The number of used balls by Wednesday is $4+T+1=5+T$.

The probability of getting two used balls is
$$p=\sum_{0\le t\le3}\binom{3}{2}\frac{(5+T)(4+T)(4-T)}{9\cdot8\cdot7}P(T=t)$$ 
which can be easily calculated.

Comment: I think you also should multiply each component of the sum by $P(T = t)$

Comment: @DF oh my so sorry for the typo

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, i am just wondering how you got the expressions for P(T=0), P(T=1),... , was it total probability formula?

Comment: @cdummie It's just brute force combinatorics haha